# How to pass functional interface operation as parameter in Kotlin?

Tags: java, lambda, kotlin, functional-interface

Given this functional interface in Java:

```
public interface Condition<T> {
   boolean check(T target);
}
```

The operation produce by that interface can be passed as parameter to the constructor of a class:

```
new ValidationRule<>(description,problem,target-> target.length() >= 2)
```

The third argument is a Condition interface where the operation to be perform is explicitly specified as:

```
target -> target.length() >= 2
```

I am having trouble duplicating this pattern in Kotlin. How can this be done in kotlin? Is there a kotlin specific way to do this.

PS I am new to Kotlin.

Comment: did you read chapters "lambdas" and "higher order functions" in the docs?

Comment: @TimCastelijns yes I did but I still have trouble understanding the this pattern and the pattern specified in that documentation can be used in similar ways! Maybe I just failed to understand

Comment: There are plenty of examples showing the syntax here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html. Have you at least tried anything? What?

Answer (score 1):

Should be as simple as

```
typealias Condition<T> = (T) -> Boolean

class ValidationRule<T>(val description: T, val problem: T, val condition: Condition<T>) 

val validationRule = ValidationRule(description, problem, { target -> target.length() >= 2 })
```

Comment: If the interface already exists in Java, then you don't need the typealias.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The problem is not translating from one syntax to the other the problem is that the parameter wont accept the lambda expression as an argument.

Comment: You might need to specify the `, problem, Condition<SomeType> { target ->`